# Eclipse juno won't deploy to tomcat 7 because of org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:<project> missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I suddenly started getting error when eclipse tries to build my workspace.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on project 'pepper'.
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants
```

Since I am getting this error all my project are not getting deployed to tomcat. If I go server configuration Servers view -> Right click -> Open -> Modules tab. I can see following in Module column.

```
org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:<projectName> missing
```

This is same for all my projects.

I am using Eclipse Juno. I was able to deploy all the project a while ago. Only thing I did was installing BPMN 2.0 eclipse plugin from http://eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/. I have tried to uninstall it but nothing's changed.

Error log is saying following.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.EarFacetValidator.validate(EarFacetValidator.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectValidationBuilder.build(FacetedProjectValidationBuilder.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Add lines below to dependencies section:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jst</groupId>
    <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.105-v200709122200</version>
  </dependency>
```

source: http://mavenhub.com/c/org/eclipse/jst/j2ee/project/facet/ij2eefacetconstants/dependency